# how parse xml with many roots on php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, simplexml

I wanna read a XML but this XML have many roots in the same XML:

```
[obtenerResult] => 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <node1>
     <node2></node2>
   </node1>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<node4>
    <node5></node5>
</node4>
```

How can read the nodes with simplexml on PHP.

I try `$rXML=simplexml_load_string($result->obtenerResult->node4);` but it doesn't work

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If it has many roots, its not really xml.

Comment: That XML is invalid, wrap it in a new root?

Comment: yes, but how can read el val of nodes?

Thx for your help

Comment: @Scuzzy Wrapping in a new root won't help in this case (without other manipulation as well), because the `<?xml ?>` directive is explicitly forbidden anywhere but the start of a document.

Answer (score 1):

You could manipulate the string and split them into separate XML documents, and iterate over each document separately...

```
$result = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><node1><node2></node2></node1><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><node4><node5></node5></node4>';

$header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'; // Where to split the XML

foreach(array_filter(explode($header,$result)) as $xmlDocument)
{
  $xmlDocument = $header . $xmlDocument; // Restore the header
  var_dump($xmlDocument); // Work with each XML document here
}
```

*(This code assumes the XML headers are the same)*

Comment: You can split using a pattern: `$xmlData = preg_split("/(<\?[^>]*>)/", $result, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` would get you an array where every even key is the header and odd key is the body. Then just for loop over incrementing $i by 2 every time. Then $i is header and $i+1 is body. http://codepad.viper-7.com/Vgj6OP

Comment: Yeah that would be a great idea, perhaps explicitly state its the XML tag as well `'/(<\?xml[^>]*>)/'`

Comment: If you're worried about different attributes or order inside the `<?xml ?>` directive, just make `$header` be the bit you know for sure will be there: `$header = '<?xml ';`. Since it gets added back inside the loop, it doesn't matter that it's not a whole line, and you don't need to faff with regular expressions.